# How would callback occur when passing array of pointers into a function?

Tags: c, pointers

When I pass an array of pointers through a sort function, I have another function for the swapping.

What exact variables (of the array of pointers) do I pass into the swap function?

Not using the swap as a function but actually just copying that directly into the sort works.

```
typedef struct team
{
  int val;
} team;

void swap(team *t1, team *t2);
void sort(team *t[4]);

void swap(team *t1, team *t2)
{
  team *t = t1;
  t1 = t2;
  t2 = t;
}

void sort(team *t[4])
{
  printf("t[0] is %d\n", t[0]);
  // I have a sorting algorithm here that uses this swap
  swap(t[0], t[1]);
  printf("t[0] is %d\n", t[0]);
}

int main()
{
  team table[4] = {2, 6, 7, 8};
  team *aop[4] = {&table[0], &table[1], &table[2], &table[3]};
  sort(aop);
  return 0;
}
```

BTW I'm a total noob here, any other tips on how to ask a question or coding in general would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The swap function that you are using takes each of its pointer arguments by value, however, for the desired functionality it is required to take them by (pointer) reference.

The distinction to be made here is that swap takes values of type `team` by (pointer) reference (i.e., `team *`), but it takes values of type `team *` by value. Hence, it only swaps its local references, which is why it works if it is directly inserted into your `sort` function.

Instead, consider the following implementation of `swap`

```
void swap(team **t1, team **t2)
{
  team *t = *t1;
  *t1 = *t2;
  *t2 = t;
}
```

In this case, `swap` takes (pointer) references to values of type `team *`, and swaps them. This will now work for the intended use case.

Comment: What arguments would i pass into the function?
How would I pass the address of the pointers in my array of pointers into the function?

Answer (score 0):

Your `swap` function do nothing, because C uses `call by value`. You have to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
void swap(team **t1, team **t2)
{
  team **t = t1;

  *t1 = *t2;
  *t2 = t;
}
```

Now you pass the address of the pointer into the function and manipulate the data at the given address.

```
t[0] is 2
t[0] is 6
```

You can test it [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler).

Edit: The previous one was faster :)